# All variables in the Storage

Tags: storage, get-storage-at

I am a newbie at Ethereum, could you clarify one question.

Is it possible to see all variables within Storage of the Contract? If I don't know how many variables it has and want to see the list of all variables.

As I understood, *getStorageAt(adr, pos)* function requires the exact position (and the number of variables so that).

Thank a lot!

Comment: I think it should be possible to determine all the positions used by a contract, but I don't think it should be easy. The hard way is to trace all contract transactions and collect positions used. Other possibility is to try to extract addresses used from the Ethereum World State, but I'm not sure if it is possible.